# Orthogonals, U,

Tags: linear-algebra

Given U = $\{(x,y,z) \in R^3 | x - y = 0\}$

1. The orthogonal complement of U is a sub space with dimension ?
2. The orthognal projection of $v = (1,0,1)$ on $U^{\bot}$ is $(-0.5,0.5,0)$ ?

   My solution:

1.Easy to see after some steps that $U = Sp\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ So its dimension is 2 and $U^{\bot}$ dimension is 1. So its not true. ( Btw: whats the vector that spans $U^{\bot}$ ?

Question 2. No idea how to solve. Thought somwhow to implement $a-u \bot U$. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector spanning the perpendicular space will be $w = (1,-1,0)$.  In fact, we can notice that $U$ is defined by
$$
U = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 \mid (x,y,z)\cdot (1,-1,0) = 0\}
$$
With this in mind, the projection onto $U^\perp$ will simply be the projection onto the vector $w$.

So, for $v = (1,0,1)$, the projection onto $U^\perp$ will be
$$
\text{proj}_w(v) = \frac{w \cdot v}{v \cdot v} v
$$

Comment: Where did u find the formula for computing $proj_{w}(v)$?

Comment: This is well known (and often useful).  You usually see it in texts for multivariable calculus.  It is equivalent to projecting onto the unit vector in the $v$ direction by finding
$$
\left[w \cdot \left(\frac{v}{\|v\|}\right)\right]
\left(\frac{v}{\|v\|} \right)
$$

Comment: Got it now. I have a similar formula written a lil different but its multiply so its pretty the same. Thank you very much!